# No such file or directory when archiving

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I added Firebase to my Xcode project using cocoapods. I can build and it succeeds, I only get this warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/game-dwgqybwtgjx..../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/game/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/game-dwgqybwtgj..../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/game/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Protobuf'
```

The build succeeds but the archive doesn't.

When I click archive I get these warnings and errors:

```
/Users/..../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/game-dwgqybwtg.../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/game/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/game.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the problem by updating macOS and Xcode